# Sorting in Storybook: Possible to force an order for nested stories?

Tags: javascript, storybook

My Storybook uses the following grouping for stories:

```
Introduction
Styleguide
Atoms
  Component
     README
     Examples
  Component
     README
     Examples
Molecules
  Component
     README
     Examples
Organisms
  Component
     README
     Examples
```

- Basically three groups: Atoms, Molecules, and Organisms.
- Each group should have alphabetized components. This currently works.
- Each component has a README mdx file, and then all stories nested under Examples.

I’m currently sorting stories like this:

```js
options: {
    storySort: {
        method: 'alphabetical',
        order: ['Introduction', 'Styleguide', 'Atoms', 'Molecules', 'Organisms'],
        locales: 'en-US',
    }
},
```

This gets me *close*, but the README and Examples within component stories appear in alphabetical order when I want README to appear first.

Is this possible?

Comment: From what I can tell this does not work as of today (v6.3). But I took the freedom to open a [feature request](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/16573) and quoted you there. Fingers crossed it gets accepted - I'll report back when there is a reaction from the dev team.

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar problem, and I could find a way of doing as you requested, after finding this info on the [storybook documentation](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/naming-components-and-hierarchy#sorting-stories):
[image]

For your specific case, I think that you could do something like this:

```
options: {
    storySort: {
        method: 'alphabetical',
        order: ['Introduction', 'Styleguide', 'Atoms', ['Readme', '*'], 'Molecules', ['Readme', '*'], 'Organisms', ['Readme', '*']],
        locales: 'en-US',
    }
},
```

Basically, you just have to add `, ['Readme', '*']` after every group that you like to sort by using the `Readme first` custom order.
This just indicates storybook to display the `Readme` story first, and then the rest of the stories.

This approach solves the problem, but I think that the solution could be improved by writing your own storySort functions, as indicated on [this comment in github](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/6327#issuecomment-664900197)

I hope this answer would be helpful for your scenario too.

Regards